# How do you set the maximum height for a peak in peakutils [python]

Tags: python

I am currently using the peakutils package to identify peaks in python. However I am not sure how to only index peaks that have a certain height. Is there a function for this?

```
indexes = peakutils.indexes(data, thres=0.02/max(data), min_dist=5)
```

That's my current index code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threshold is normalized, so thres=0.8 will only detect peaks with amplitude higher than 80% of the data range. That is, if your data is y = [90, 95, 100], then thres=0.8 will result in an actual threshold of 98.

Note: there was a bug in the threshold calculation (fixed today).